# Browserstack & Testcafe: Possible to use without localetesting

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, browserstack

We want to run TestCafe Tests with BrowserStack Devices. Our tests are complex and at the moment they don't work via BrowserStack because some elements are not visible within BrowserStack.
It seems that it is caused by the LocalTesting.

Is it possible to run the tests without LocalTesting? Or has anyone a solution to this test-scenario?

Answer (score 2):

Reading through https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-browser-provider-browserstack#browserstack-proxy-options, there is an environment variable `BROWSERSTACK_NO_LOCAL` when set to `1` should disable the local testing completely.

However, from my view, this will not allow the remote browser to connect to the runner if the IP from which the test is initiated is not public.

As per the local testing implementation on Browserstack, any publicly accessible URL will directly resolve from the internet unless the Force Local option is set in which case **all** the network traffic routes via your network.

The TestCafe options also has `BROWSERSTACK_FORCE_LOCAL` to enable force local. You'll simply need to remove it, if the flag is set.